# Django Rest Framework Serializer Relations: How to get a list of only the latest track?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm following this documentation [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#rest-framework-generic-relations). I'm trying to wrap my head around being able to query the Album object and have it only return the latest track versus returning all the tracks. Below is a modified version of the documentation models and serializers.

Models

```
class AlbumOwner(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AlbumOwner, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'created_at'
```

Serializers

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('title', 'created_at')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'tracks')
```

The query I am currently using is below, "o" represents the owner:

```
albums = Album.objects.filter(owner=o)
serializer = AlbumSerializer(albums)
serializer.data
```

Serializer.data will return a response similar to this:

```
[{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'tracks': [
        {'title': 'Public Service Announcement', "created_at": "2018-06-15T06:22:35.680291Z"},
        {'title': 'What More Can I Say', "created_at": "2014-07-15T06:22:35.680291Z"},
        {'title': 'Encore', "created_at": "2016-07-15T06:22:35.680291Z"}
    ],
},{
    'album_name': 'The Blue Album',
    'tracks': [
        {'title': 'PSA', "created_at": "2002-07-15T06:22:35.680291Z"},
        {'title': 'WMCIS', '"created_at": "2003-07-15T06:22:35.680291Z"},
        {'title': 'E', "created_at": "2005-07-15T06:22:35.680291Z"}
    ],
},
]
```

The response I want is where only tracks of the latest date are returned:

```
[{
        'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
        'tracks': [
            {'title': 'Public Service Announcement', "created_at": "2018-06-15T06:22:35.680291Z"}
        ],
    },{
        'album_name': 'The Blue Album',
        'tracks': [
            {'title': 'E', "created_at": "2005-07-15T06:22:35.680291Z"}
        ],
    },
    ]
```

Comment: Since you know about ``get_latest_by`` - you can use .latest() of your Track manager - Track.objects.latest() and feed it to the TrackSerializer - no need for slicing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like below, i.e. slice the tracks queryset or select the latest one based on some filter.

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'tracks')

    def get_tracks(self, album):
        qs = album.tracks.all()[-1:]
        return TrackSerializer(qs, many=True, read_only=True).data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a few questions:
Do I need to call `get_tracks` anywhere? Or is the Serializer smart enough to know to use it? What is the `source='latest_track'` referencing?

How many database calls would I be making in this case?

Comment: No, you don't need to call `get_tracks()`, it will be called automatically as it follows a `get_<field_name>()` pattern.  `tracks` is the <field_name> in case (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). My bad, `source='latest_track'` shouldn't be there, fixed.

Comment: It looks like `qs = album.tracks.all()[:1]` returns the first created track instead of the latest created track. I have added ordering to the models and they should be sorted in reverse chronological order. I have attempted variations on your query such as `albumn.tracks.reverse()[0]` (errors out on object is not iterable),  `qs = albumn.tracks..all()[1:]` (returns the latest 2 entries, I just want 1). What am I missing here?

Comment: `albumn.tracks.reverse()[0]` return's a single item, not an iterable (list, queryset, ...). If `qs = album.tracks.all()[:1]` returns the first track, try to use `qs = album.tracks.all()[-1:]` to get the last one.